# comparing interval of date with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a booking system . and I have a problem with my SQL request .
this is my table :

http://sardoukayoub.com/1.png

And this is my SQL request :

```
"SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE (‘2014-01-09' BETWEEN DateDebut AND DateFin ) OR (‘2014-01-24' BETWEEN DateDebut AND DateFin ))AS A WHERE IdProduit = 320"
```

the result of my request with these two date get me this line : 
http://sardoukayoub.com/2.png

I want to perform my request to get me 2 lines . in my case the idreservation=21 and 22 .

Comment: Doesn't look possible. id 21 has a `DateDebut` of 2014-01-10, and you're asking for 2014-01-09 in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to check if two periods overlap:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations 
WHERE DateDebut <= '2014-01-29' AND DateFin >= '2014-01-12'
AND IdProduit = 320;
```

Btw, in Standard SQL there's an OVERLAPS operator :-)

Answer (score 0):

The date

```
'2014-01-09'
```

u selected in your statement is not between DateDebut and DateFin in the table where IdProduit=320

This should work fine

```
SELECT * FROM reservations 
WHERE DateDebut <= '2014-01-29' AND DateFin >= '2014-01-12'
AND IdProduit = 320;"
```

Comment: Well ,i want a request that between these two dates 2014-01-09 / 2014-01-24 give a result of two reservations "id : 21 and 22 " . my request give me just one result

Comment: I have just tried with 2014-01-12 and 2014-01-29 . the request give just one result id:22 .The request that i need have to return 2 lines . 12 is Beetwen 10 and 17 .

Comment: i changed the query and i don't think it should bother u any further.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE (DateFin BETWEEN '2014-01-12' AND '2014-01-29') OR (DateDebut BETWEEN '2014-01-12' AND '2014-01-29'))AS A WHERE IdProduit = 320"  , with this one It's work for all my cases :D

Comment: This will miss a reservation with DateDebut '2014-01-11' and DateFin '2014-01-30'.

Comment: @dnoeth y not? if i change it as (DateFin BETWEEN '2014-01-11' AND '2014-01-30') both the rows will be displayed.The user has to change the dates everytime as per the requirement.

Comment: You will not find an existing row with DateDebut '2014-01-11' and DateFin '2014-01-30' when you use "WHERE (DateFin BETWEEN '2014-01-12' AND '2014-01-29') OR (DateDebut BETWEEN '2014-01-12' AND '2014-01-29')"

Comment: @dnoeth yepp  that's true. Was thinking the other way. Thanks :)